# On compactness in open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $K\subset\Omega$ be compact. Then show that there exists an $r>0$ such that the set

$\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n : ||y-x||\leq r$ for some $x$ in $K\}$

is compact in $\Omega$.

Any direction/help would be useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is small enough the the set is contained in $\Omega$: this is because the distance between the compact set $K$ and the closed set $\Omega^{c} $ is positive. We can take any $ r \in (0, d(K,\Omega^{c})$. Once we choose $r$ to make this  a subset of $\Omega$ we just observe that the set is closed and bounded, hence compact.

Comment: I have a doubt. What does compactness in an open set mean? For instance, $(0,1]$ is closed and bounded in $(0,\infty)$, but is it compact?

Comment: For a subset $A$ of $\Omega$ there is no difference between compactness in $\Omega$ and compactness in $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: That means Heine-Borel remains true for any open set in euclidean space as well, is it?

Comment: @WhySee Yes, you can use Heine Borel Theorem here.

Comment: Thank you. That was precisely my doubt here.